# Why is jQuery removeClass reappearing on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a 2 logos in it and on scroll the first logo hides and the second appears using classes. On reverse scroll the second logo should hide and the first reappear. The first is reappearing but the second is hiding then reappearing when I reach the top of the page.

I've been going around in circles and I can't understand why on reverse scroll the 'show-logo' class is reappearing. Can anyone explain why?

JS:

```
if ($(window).width() > 640){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var header    = $(".site-header");

  if (scrollTop > 50) {
    header.addClass("scrolling");
    setTimeout(function() {
      header.addClass("show-logo");
    }, 500);
  }
  else {
    header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
  };
} else {
  header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably because of the timeout? maybe you need to cancel it

Comment: But the timeout should only execute when the scrollTop position is more than 50 so if it's less than 50 why would it then reappear. Apologies, I'm not great at this so want to understand why? Any explanation you can share would be appreciated.

Comment: so when you scroll and it is pass 50 and it sets the timeout and you scroll some more and it is less than 50 that timeout is still there waiting to run..... and since scroll fires alot, you are making tons of timeouts. Add  `console.log('timer', new Date())` inside of it and watch.

Comment: Add the `$(window).scrollTop()` check inside the setTimeout (as well as where it is)

Comment: Ok so I need to cancel the timeout function after it's executed? How would I do that? In the else or before?

Comment: Not after it's executed - that would only be needed if using `setInterval` - `setTimeout` only fires once ... each time it is called and it's called each time you scroll.

Comment: Could you provide a link to any examples I'm a little lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setTimeout has no clue that it should not run so it runs. So if you do not want it to execute it, you need to cancel it. Two different ways depending on what you want to happen.

```
var myTimer = null;
var header = $(".site-header");
var win = $(window);
win.on("scroll", function() {
  if (myTimer) {
    window.clearTimeout(myTimer)
  }
  if ($(win.width() > 640) {
    var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolling");
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        header.addClass("show-logo");
      }, 500);
    } else {
       header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
    }
  } else {
    header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
  }
});
```

or

```
var myTimer = null;
var header = $(".site-header");
var win = $(window);
win.on("scroll", function() {      
  if ($(win.width() > 640) {
    var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolling");
      if (!myTimer) {
        myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          header.addClass("show-logo");
        }, 500);
      }
    } else {
       header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
       if (myTimer) {
         window.clearTimeout(myTimer)
         myTimer = null
       }
    }
  } else {
    header.removeClass("show-logo scrolling");
  }
});
```

Comment: I had been trying to do it like your first example but for some reason the show-logo class was being added but the logo wasn't displaying. I'm currently trying to figure out what's wrong. I really appreciate you taking the time to provide your examples.

Comment: The second logo seems to only appear when I stop scrolling.

Comment: hence why I added the second one where it should show up

Comment: And I've just realised that. Haha sorry I should have checked. Really really appreciate your help on this.